# Calculating sinuosity of a path with GME in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, analysis

Does anyone have any experience with pathmetrics in GME?

I would ideally like to use the old Hawths's tool "line metrics" for calculating sinuosity of a daily path but I have ArcGIS 10. I downloaded GME & R and have run some things successfully (e.g. min convex polygon), but have had lots of problems trying to run "path metrics" in GME. It basically won't run and I don't know why. I get an output that says 0 files created.

Also, the format of my 'time' column in the original xls file doesn't seem to get copied when I create a polyline - it ends up with no time codes (shows 0:00:00 in every row). this means I can't easily calculate the time intervals (and so the rate of path movement). 
Is there a specific time format that is needed?

Lastly, imagining that I do get it to run, how do I calculate the path sinuosity from the segment lengths, turn angles etc..?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is an implementation of sinuosity... have a look at the python toolbox code example (bottom of link page) it contains an implementation of sinuosity.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_toolbox/001500000022000000/